# Need help in coverting a string value using regular expression in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to replace string value length from xml tag from 8 or more characters to fixed 7 characters in notepad++.What I have tried till now is !!

in Find what:

```
<Tag>([a-zA-Z0-9 ]{8,})</Tag>
```

in replace with :

```
<Tag>\1{7}</Tag>
```

This is the string I want to replace:

```
<Tag>E2EDL20003         </Tag>   
<Tag>E2EDL22            </Tag>    
<Tag>E2EDL22 </Tag>  
<Tag>E2EDL2</Tag>
```

Expected results:

```
<Tag>E2EDL20</Tag>    
<Tag>E2EDL22</Tag>   
<Tag>E2EDL22</Tag>  
<Tag>E2EDL2</Tag>
```

actual results:

```
<Tag>E2EDL20003         {7}</Tag>  
<Tag>E2EDL22            {7}</Tag>  
<Tag>E2EDL22 {7}</Tag>  
<Tag>E2EDL2</Tag>
```

Comment: Perhaps `(<Tag>[A-Z0-9]+)\h+(</Tag>)` See https://regex101.com/r/OzzCIv/1 and replace with 2 capturing groups.

Comment: Thank you and sorry ..I have editied the query again. My requirement is I need the value length to be 7 characters by trimming the remaining.

Comment: Did you check the `Regular Expression` option?

Comment: Can the first 7 chars also contain a whitespace or do you only want to remove the whitespace after 7 chars `A-Z0-9`?

Answer (score 0):

Search for:

```
<Tag>([a-zA-Z0-9 ]{7}).*
```

(make sure `.` does not match newline), and replace with:

```
<Tag>\1</Tag>
```

Note that since you want

```
<Tag>E2EDL22 </Tag>
```

to turn into

```
<Tag>E2EDL22</Tag>
```

because `E2EDL22` only has 7 characters, not 8, you should use `{7` to match the characters on the left, not `{8`, in order to trim that final space.

Comment: Ok, see edit, best to make sure your question is asking for what you want when you post it

Comment: I think the search text should have a final `</Tag>`, otherwise it will consume and delete everything until end-of-line. Maybe also a non-greedy `.*?` instead. I know that end-of-line behaviour is not specified in the question, but I prefer my regexs to be restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the reply. Tried some changes and got my requirement.

In Find With:
([a-zA-Z0-9]{7})([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)

In Replace:
\1